# Calling string.matches(PATTERN) giving different result than Pattern.compile(PATTERN).matcher(string).hasMatches()

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to write a small java library and currently i am trying to read a file line by line, and if in a line i find the expression "!includes .yaml" i want to get the file name, load it and replace it in the current file that I am reading. For exmaple in the order file:

```
orderNo: A001
date: 2019-04-17
customerName: Customer, Joe
orderLines:
  - item: No. 9 Sprockets
    quantity: 12
    unitPrice: 1.23
  - item: Widget (10mm)
    quantity: 4
    unitPrice: 3.45
  - !include item.yaml
```

I want to replace the last line with the content of file item.yaml which looks something like

```
item: Sub-item
quantity: 2
unitPrice: 16
```

To that end i am currently playing around with regex to match the whole "!includes .yaml", which looks something like this:

```
    private static final Pattern includePattern = Pattern.compile(".*!include (?<fileName>.*\\.(yaml|yml))");
    public static String readConfiguration(String configurationFile) {
        final var configurationFileUrl = ConfigurationLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(configurationFile);
        if (configurationFileUrl == null)
            throw new ConfigurationReadException(configurationFile);
        try {
            final var lines = Files.readAllLines(Path.of(configurationFileUrl.toURI()));
            for (final var line : lines) {
                final var matcher = includePattern.matcher(line);
                if (matcher.hasMatch()) {
                    final var includedFileName = matcher.group("fileName");
                    final var includedConfiguration = readConfiguration(includedFileName);
                }
            }
            return lines.stream().reduce("", (existing, current) -> existing.equals("") ? current : "%s\r\n%s".formatted(existing, current));
        } catch (IOException | OutOfMemoryError | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException |
                 FileSystemNotFoundException | URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new ConfigurationReadException(configurationFile.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is that matcher.hasMatch() always returns false and the matcher has no match on the group, even though when I am debugging to that position in the code and execute line.matches(includePattern.pattern) I actually get "true".

I understand that .hasMatches/matches only returns true when the entire string matches the regex, but thats why i modified my pattern in a way that it actually should match the entire line. Testing with online regex testers also tells me, that my regex should be working. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to hear you figured out the problem.

The *Matcher* class works dynamically.  Meaning, you have to invoke it to generate an output.
It won't have all the data upon instantiation.

So, for the *[hasMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hasMatch())* method, as you mentioned, it requires a match, initially.

> *"... Returns whether this contains a valid match from a previous match or find operation. ..."*

As a note, I typically use the *[find](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())* method in this situation.

```java
if (matcher.find()) {
    final var includedFileName = matcher.group("fileName");
    final var includedConfiguration = readConfiguration(includedFileName);
}
```

And, as a final note, you could reduce the pattern.
The initial `.*`, the capture group, nor the set union, are required.

```
!include (?<fileName>.*\.ya?ml)
```

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted, this is actually a quite helpful comment. I saw threads on here talking about using find() but i did not put 2 and 2 together that I could also use it to initialize the matcher using find() instead. Also nice simplyfication of the regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, literally 5 minutes after posting my question I find the answer in a different thread after searching for an hour beforehand.`final var matcher = includePattern.matcher(line);` there HAS to be a call `matcher.matches()` before calling any other method on the matcher.

Comment: What's the regex question ?